# how to ignore a value of a UITextField that has already been calculated in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm trying to make an app that is very basic. One part of the app is that there are 4 textFields and a button that calculates the sum of these textFields. 
The problem that I'm facing is that say I type the value 10 in the first textField then I press the button. The result would be 10. However, if I press it again ( without typing anything in the other textFields), the result would be 20!! Furthermore, if I type 20 in one of the other textFields, the result would be 40!!
The result SHOULD BE 30 NOT 40!!
one possible option I thought of (haven't tried it yet) is assigning 0 to all of the textFields when pressing the button. But I'd like the app to be smarter and keep tracks of the result.

if it helps, here's the code inside the button that calculates the sum:

```
 @IBAction func calBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var benifit:[Double] = []

    var textFields: [Double] = []



    if initialBalance.text?.isEmpty ?? true {

             // do nothing

    } else {

        if let temp = initialBalance.text {

            // these lines of code will convert arabic numbers to English ones in case the user uses Arabic number

            let initialStr: String = temp
            let initialFormatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            initialFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "EN") as Locale!
            let initialFinal = initialFormatter.number(from: initialStr)
            benifit.append(Double(initialFinal!))
        }
    }



    if income.text?.isEmpty ?? true {

        // do nothing


    } else {

        if let temp = income.text {

        // these lines of code will convert Arabic numbers to English ones in case the user uses Arabic number

            let incomeStr: String = temp
            let incomeFormatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            incomeFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "EN") as Locale!
            let incomeFinal = incomeFormatter.number(from: incomeStr)
             benifit.append(Double(incomeFinal!))
        }
    }



    if salaries.text?.isEmpty ?? true {

        // do nothing


    } else {

        if let temp = salaries.text {

            let salariesStr: String = temp
            let salariesFormatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            salariesFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "EN") as Locale!
            let salariesFinal = salariesFormatter.number(from: salariesStr)
            textFields.append(Double(salariesFinal!))
        }
    }


    if tools.text?.isEmpty ?? true {

        // do nothing

    } else {

        if let temp = tools.text {

            let toolsStr: String = temp
            let toolsFormatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            toolsFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "EN") as Locale!
            let toolsFinal = toolsFormatter.number(from: toolsStr)
            textFields.append(Double(toolsFinal!))
        }
    }



    if maintinance.text?.isEmpty ?? true {

        // do nothing

    } else {

        if let temp = maintinance.text {

            let maintinanceStr: String = temp
            let maintinanceFormatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            maintinanceFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "EN") as Locale!
            let maintinanceFinal = maintinanceFormatter.number(from: maintinanceStr)
            textFields.append(Double(maintinanceFinal!))
        }
    }


    if other.text?.isEmpty ?? true {

        // do nothing


    } else {

        if let temp = other.text {

        let otherStr: String = temp
        let otherFormatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        otherFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "EN") as Locale!
        let otherFinal = otherFormatter.number(from: otherStr)
        textFields.append(Double(otherFinal!))
        }
    }

    for textField in textFields {

        sumExpenses += textField
    }

    for ben in benifit{

        sumBenifit += ben
    }

    totalExpenses.text =  String(sumExpenses)

     totalAfterSubtractingExpenses.text = String( sumBenifit - sumExpenses )

    sumBenifit -= sumExpenses

}
```

Comment: Not in relation to your problem, but you should probably use arrays for this code. You repeat the same five lines multiple times, just for the different buttons, and it makes your code harder to read and not concise at all.

Comment: In fact, you already have an array of textFields so why aren't you using it??

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I'm not quite sure I understand you. which five lines am I repeating? is it the five lines to convert Arabic numbers to English? I'D REALLY REALLY LOVE TO MAKE MY CODE MORE CONCISE

Comment: Yes, it is those lines. Since you are performing the same tasks for each textField, you should just be able to use the array of textFields to iterate through each textField and perform the tasks.

Comment: ohhh, you're right and makes total sense. I'll edit that. Thanks man, GREAT advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found your problem.

You use a variable `sumBenefit` which isn't declared in your func, so I assume it is declared in your UIViewController.

Since it is an instance variable, it will not reset each time you click the button.

If you want to reset the values of `sumExpenses` and `sumBenefits` each time the button is pressed, then you'll have to do something like this:

```
sumExpenses = 0
for textField in textFields {
    sumExpenses = Int(textField.text)!
}

sumBenefit = 0
for ben in benefit {
    sumBenefit += ben 
}
```

I am also making the assumption that you want a number from your textField in the first for-loop, because if `sumExpenses` is of type `Int` (or any other number for that matter) then `sumExpenses += textField` will not compile. You need to take the text of that `textField` and convert it to an `Int`.

Again, I am still not super clear what you are trying to do, but please let me know if this works for you, or if you need further clarification.

Comment: sumBenefit is a global variable inside the same class as the code I provided. I'll try your suggestion and get back here

Comment: @user2066392 No problem. Happy to help :)